Parametric Linear Programming Problem solving for allowable ranges

This is an assignment problem I have successfully solved the first part by the theory I could find in the course books 
However I lack the theory and knowledge to move on with the second part, any help/ hints would be highly appreciated I'm stuck for a long time now and I do not know how to move ahead.
